# Give same color to errorFields and bullets in amCharts

Tags: amcharts

I want assign the same color to bullets and errorFields. But I can't.

Also, I the legend on the right shows graph names only, but not bullets.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
  },

  "dataProvider": [ {
    "date": "2015-06",
    "Panama Hat": "13.42",
    "error": 14.31
  }, {
    "date": "2015-07",
    "Unsinkable": "150.18",
    "error": 5.3
  }, {
    "date": "2015-07",
    "Panama Hat": "141.24",
    "error": 6.08
  }, {
    "date": "2015-07",
    "Unsinkable": "146.09",
    "error": 6.28
  }, {
    "date": "2015-09",
    "Unsinkable": "122.24",
    "error": 15.56
  }, {
    "date": "2015-09",
    "Panama Hat": "144.84",
    "error": 11.93
  }, {
    "date": "2015-10",
    "Unsinkable": "167.31",
    "error": 18.75
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {

    "maximum": 194.56,
    "minimum": -75.13,
    "dashLength": 5,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "SpeedFig",
    "id": "v1",
  } ],
  "startDuration": 0,
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "g0",
    "balloonText": "Panama Hat<br>[[category]]: SPDFIG [[value]]<br>Error : [[error]]",
    "bullet": "yError",
    "bulletSize": 7,
    "errorField": "error",
    "lineThickness": 1,
    "valueField": "Panama Hat",
    "bulletAxis": "v1",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "title": "Panama Hat"
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "valueField": "Panama Hat",
    "lineAlpha": 0
  }, {
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonText": "Unsinkable<br>[[category]]: SPDFIG [[value]]<br>Error : [[error]]",
    "bullet": "yError",
    "bulletSize": 7,
    "errorField": "error",
    "lineThickness": 1,
    "valueField": "Unsinkable",
    "bulletAxis": "v1",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "title": "Unsinkable"
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "valueField": "Unsinkable",
    "lineAlpha": 0
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false,
    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY MMM DD",
    "oneBalloonOnly": true
  },
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM",
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "MM",
    "dateFormats": [ {
      period: 'fff',
      format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
    }, {
      period: 'ss',
      format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
    }, {
      period: 'mm',
      format: 'JJ:NN'
    }, {
      period: 'hh',
      format: 'JJ:NN'
    }, {
      period: 'DD',
      format: 'MMM DD'
    }, {
      period: 'WW',
      format: 'MMM DD'
    }, {
      period: 'MM',
      format: 'MMM YYYY'
    }, {
      period: 'YYYY',
      format: 'MMM YYYY'
    } ],
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "libs": {
      "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/libs/"
    }
  }

} );
```

Comment: Thanks martynasma you really resolved a big issue for me. I was really under stress and your code made my life much easier. I really appreciate you help and thanks once again. It's really a life saving for me-:)

Comment: Please martynasma help me : i am stuck when I click on the legend then bullets are not hiding even though lines are hiding I want to have a way where bullets can also be hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the same [`lineColor`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#lineColor) for two graphs that use share the same `valueField`. This way you will ensure that they do not get autoa-assigned different colors.

As for the legend. I suggest you hide the secondary graphs (the ones used to display bullet) from the legend using [`visibleInLegend: false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#visibleInLegend).

I'd also remove `useGraphSettings` from legend config, and set `marketType: "circle".

Here's the same chart with the above changes:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "markerType": "circle",
    "markerSize": 10
  },

  "dataProvider": [{
    "date": "2015-06",
    "Panama Hat": "13.42",
    "error": 14.31
  }, {
    "date": "2015-07",
    "Unsinkable": "150.18",
    "error": 5.3
  }, {
    "date": "2015-07",
    "Panama Hat": "141.24",
    "error": 6.08
  }, {
    "date": "2015-07",
    "Unsinkable": "146.09",
    "error": 6.28
  }, {
    "date": "2015-09",
    "Unsinkable": "122.24",
    "error": 15.56
  }, {
    "date": "2015-09",
    "Panama Hat": "144.84",
    "error": 11.93
  }, {
    "date": "2015-10",
    "Unsinkable": "167.31",
    "error": 18.75
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{

    "maximum": 194.56,
    "minimum": -75.13,
    "dashLength": 5,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "SpeedFig",
    "id": "v1",
  }],
  "startDuration": 0,
  "graphs": [{
    "id": "g0",
    "balloonText": "Panama Hat<br>[[category]]: SPDFIG [[value]]<br>Error : [[error]]",
    "lineColor": "#67b7dc",
    "bullet": "yError",
    "bulletSize": 7,
    "errorField": "error",
    "lineThickness": 1,
    "valueField": "Panama Hat",
    "bulletAxis": "v1",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "title": "Panama Hat"
  }, {
    "lineColor": "#67b7dc",
    "bullet": "round",
    "valueField": "Panama Hat",
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "visibleInLegend": false
  }, {
    "id": "g1",
    "lineColor": "#fdd400",
    "balloonText": "Unsinkable<br>[[category]]: SPDFIG [[value]]<br>Error : [[error]]",
    "bullet": "yError",
    "bulletSize": 7,
    "errorField": "error",
    "lineThickness": 1,
    "valueField": "Unsinkable",
    "bulletAxis": "v1",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "title": "Unsinkable"
  }, {
    "lineColor": "#fdd400",
    "bullet": "round",
    "valueField": "Unsinkable",
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "visibleInLegend": false
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false,
    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY MMM DD",
    "oneBalloonOnly": true
  },
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM",
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "MM",
    "dateFormats": [{
      period: 'fff',
      format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
    }, {
      period: 'ss',
      format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
    }, {
      period: 'mm',
      format: 'JJ:NN'
    }, {
      period: 'hh',
      format: 'JJ:NN'
    }, {
      period: 'DD',
      format: 'MMM DD'
    }, {
      period: 'WW',
      format: 'MMM DD'
    }, {
      period: 'MM',
      format: 'MMM YYYY'
    }, {
      period: 'YYYY',
      format: 'MMM YYYY'
    }],
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "libs": {
      "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/libs/"
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```